# Importing azure.storage.blob.aio

Tags: python, azure, python-packaging

I want to use [BlobServiceClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python) in my python code.

I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError

I have installed the following packages:

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

In my python script I have tried importing the following ways

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
[from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/)
```

I still the the ModuleNotFoundError

I am using the following versions:

| Package | version |
| --- | --- |
| Python | 3.9.7 |
| azure-common | 1.1.28 |
| azure-core | 1.26.4 |
| azure-eventgrid | 4.10.0 |
| azure-identity | 1.12.0 |
| azure-keyvault | 4.2.0 |
| azure-keyvault-certificates | 4.7.0 |
| azure-keyvault-keys | 4.8.0 |
| azure-keyvault-secrets | 4.7.0 |
| azure-servicebus | 7.9.0 |
| azure-storage-blob | 12.16.0 |
| azure-storage-common | 2.1.0 |
| azure-storage-file | 2.1.0 |
| azure-storage-file-share | 12.12.0 |

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are importing the BlobServiceClient class from the azure.storage.blob.aio module with the proper import statement. You still encounter a ModuleNotFoundError, maybe a package version mismatch between the installed packages.

Try to uninstall and install the packages using the below:

```
pip uninstall azure-storage-blob
pip install azure-storage-blob
pip install aiohttp
```

I'm using `Python version = Python 3.9.13` and installed azure-storage-blob and aiohttp using the above commands.

Here is a workaround using **`azure-storage-blob-aio`** package using Python.

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient

async def main():
    # Set the connection string to your storage account
    conn_str = "Your-connection-string"
    
    # Create a BlobServiceClient object
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_str)
    
    # Get a reference to the container you want to work with
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
    
    # Create a new blob in the container
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("example-blob.txt")
    await blob_client.upload_blob("Hello, world!")
    
    # Download the blob's content
    blob_content = await blob_client.download_blob()
    print(await blob_content.content_as_text())
    
    # List all blobs in the container
    async for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
        print(blob.name)

# Run the main() function
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output:**

The above code was executed and returned the blob name successfully using **`azure-storage-blob-aio`** package.

```
Hello, world!
data.csv
example-blob.txt
myfile.txt
```

[image]